# ASP Gridview - Dynamically setting Font Properties

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am creating a Gridview dynamically, and need to also dynamically set the font properties for the Header Text and normal Cell text.

```
//generate dynamic id
GridView gv = new GridView();
gv.ID = "gv" + cnt2;
// I tried many ways, even simply setting 1 cell in 1 row, but get
// cannot be assigned to -- it is read only
// gv.Rows[1].Cells[0].Font = new Font("Tahoma", 9.75F, FontStyle.Bold);
gv.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
```

I can successfully change ForeColor and BackColor, but not Font properties at all.

Thanks to  yogihosting.
This is how I ended up doing it.

```
//generate dynamic id
GridView gv = new GridView();
gv.ID = "gv" + cnt2;
gv.HeaderStyle.CssClass = "grdHeader";
gv.RowStyle.CssClass = "grdRow";
gv.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
```

Comment: you can simply use CSS. Gridview is turned to table by the asp.net engine so you can set css like table tr td{color:#Black}, like this.

Comment: In plane html, it create table, set your css for table cells and see the effect.

Comment: Thanks.  It worked like a charm.  I was just trying to keep everything together in the code behind, but using CSS is easier.